# Converse countably additivity of Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots$ be a countable collection of pairwise disjoint measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and let's suppose $f\in L^1(A_i)$ for all $i$. Let $A=\bigcup_i A_i$. Furthermore let's suppose that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{I=1}^n\int_{A_i} f$$
exists.

Under these hypothesis I want to prove that $f\in L(A)$ and the integral is the limit above.

My idea was to consider the sequence $f_n=f\chi_{A_n}$  and then find some way to use Levi's​ monotone convergence Theorem for the series, but since $f_n$ may not be $\geq 0$ the approach​ may not work.

Any idea?

I just thought that I might use Levi's Theorem with $|f_n|$ to prove that $|f|\in L^1(A)$  and then it'd be over. Am I right?

Comment: Your "since … the approach may not work" should raise the possibility that not necessarily $f\in L^1(A)$, and suggest an idea for constructing counterexamples.

Comment: Under these hypotheses, $f\in L^1(A)$ if and only if $$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \int_{A_i} \lvert f\rvert < +\infty.$$

Comment: Construct something with $\int_{A_i} f = (-1)^i / i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem this is not true. If you take $A_i=(i,i+1)$ they are pairwise disjoint and their union is $\mathbb R^+\setminus \mathbb N$. If you take $f$ to be $i$ on $A_i$ you have that for all $i$ $f$ has finite integral on $A_i$. On the other hand by Daniel Fischer comment it is clear that $f$ is not in $L^1(A)$.

Comment: In this case, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\int_{A_i} f$ does not exist, does it? That, since $\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{A_i} f=\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: if infinity is not good then one can still use Daniel's comment to get a sequence where the limit is not in $L^1$ by taking $f$ so that it is $(-1)^n 1/n$ on $A_n$ so that $\int_{A_n} f=(-1)^n 1/n$. This is a converging series that does not converge absolutely.